# How can I calculate standard errors using bootstrap in R?

Tags: r

I have a matrix "num" containing explanatory variables with the following sample data:

```
Intercept   Num1   Num2  Num3
1           1.20   0     5.46
1           2.39   1     2.95
1           1.93   1     13.44
1           1.30   0     3.05
1           2.37   1     3.55
```

I also have a matrix "succ" containing the dependent variable with the following sample data:

```
succ
2.69
-0.71
1.96
-6.95
2.61
```

I am running a regression of succ on num. I am trying to create a bootstrap function to calculate the standard errors of the regression for each explanatory variable, to see how different the standard errors are compared to the linear regression. I do not want to use the "boot" package.

I've tried creating the following function:

```
custom.boot <- function(times, data) {
  boots <- rep(NA, times)
  for (i in 1:times) {
    boots[i] <- sd(sample(data, length(data), 
                   replace=TRUE)/sqrt(length(data)))  
  }
  boots
}
```

However, I am stuck here as I know that I will not get the values I need if I just run

```
custom.boot(1000, num)
```

I would like to just receive an output like:

```
var        std. errors
Intercept  ###
Num1       ###
Num2       ###
Num3       ###
```

Per bootstrap methodology, these should slightly differ based on the number of replications that I run. What do I need to change in my code to get this output?

Comment: So you want column-wise standard error, then a summary of these error measurements? How do you want to combine back the sampled columns?

Comment: Yes, I want to create a bootstrap function that will calculate the standard error for each explanatory variable from the regression of succ on num.

Comment: Sure, that is fine (and in your original question), how do you want to combine the 1000 std errors that you produce for each column to generate only 4 output SE's?

Comment: Ah, I see. If my understanding of bootstrap is correct, each of the 1000 replications will create a standard error for each variable. So I guess the mean of those standard errors should be sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the original question and the comments, you could try averaging like this to get a mean SE for each replication (using `sapply` and `sd` as `sd` on `data.frames` no longer works):

```
num = structure(list(Intercept = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), Num1 = c(1.2, 
        2.39, 1.93, 1.3, 2.37), Num2 = c(0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L), Num3 = c(5.46, 
        2.95, 13.44, 3.05, 3.55)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
        -5L))

custom.boot <- function(times, data) {
  boots <- rep(NA, times)
  for (i in 1:times) {
    temp.se.df = NA
    temp.se.df = sapply(sample(data, length(data), replace=TRUE), sd)/sqrt(length(data))
    boots[i] <- mean(temp.se.df)
  }
  boots
}

# this generates 1000 averaged SE's based on sampling of the `num` columns:
custom.boot(1000, num)
```